# Why does os.path.basename return an empty string when passed a path with a trailing slash?

Tags: python

Is there a principled reason why having a trailing directory delimiter in an argument to `os.path.basename` would yield an empty string? I'm not sure I can make any sense of that return value beyond it seeming like an unhandled implementation edge case or an implementation side effect.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('/tmp')
'tmp'
>>> os.path.basename('/tmp/')
''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is mentioned in the documentation

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

> Note that the result of this function is ***different*** from the Unix
>   basename program; where basename for '/foo/bar/' returns 'bar', the
>   basename() function returns an empty string ('').

Apparently it's just by choice.

Comment: This behaviour leads to the function always returning nothing or a filename, but never a directory.

Comment: Not so much due to choice, but simply an artifact of its implementation—as per @Bryan's answer.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation for `basename` states this:

> Return the base name of pathname path. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

The documentation for `os.path.split` says this (emphasis added):

> Split the pathname path into a pair, (head, tail) where tail is the last pathname component and head is everything leading up to that. The tail part will never contain a slash; **if path ends in a slash, tail will be empty**.

Calling `os.path.split` on `"/tmp/"` yields `('/tmp', '')`. Because the second element of the pair is `''`, basename returns `''`.